# Real Numbers-Write in Interval Form

Tags: real-numbers

$|5 - x^{-1}| \lt 1$

$-1 \lt 5 -\frac{1}{x} \lt 1$.

$-1-5 \lt -\frac{1}{x} \lt 1-5$.

$-6 < -\frac{1}{x}< -4$.

$6 > \frac{1}{x} > 4$.

$6x > 1 > 4x$.

I get stuck after this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$-1 \lt 5 - \frac{1}{x} \lt 1$

$-6 \lt -\frac{1}{x} \lt -4$

$4 \lt \frac{1}{x} \lt 6$

$\frac{1}{6}\lt x \lt \frac{1}{4}$

$(\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{4})$

Comment: |5 - x^(-1)| < 1

-1 < 5 -1/x < 1
-1-5 < -1/x < 1-5
-6 < -1/x < -4
6 > 1/x > 4
6x > 1 > 4x

Comment: -1 < 5 -1/x < 1
-1-5 < -1/x < 1-5
-6 < -1/x < -4
6 > 1/x > 4
6x > 1 > 4x

I get stuck after this

Comment: Thanks man really appreciated

Comment: You're welcome.